# Grid container exceeding the allowed maxwidth on mobile devices

Tags: css

I am having problems with my container layout for some reason it is passing the maximum width of my container which is 80rem I'm not able to imagine how to solve this, in my other grid layout I don't have this problem just in the last My problem is on mobile devices

example: https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-mountain-t1c1m

code:

```
<Container>
      <NewsWrapper>
        <CardTop>
          <div className="Bg" />
          <div className="headerH3">
            <h3>
              <a href="xd4">asdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd</a>
            </h3>
          </div>
        </CardTop>
        <CardTop>
          <div className="Bg" />
          <div className="headerH3">
            <h3>
              <a href="xd3">adssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss</a>
            </h3>
          </div>
        </CardTop>
        <CardTop>
          <div className="Bg" />
          <div className="headerH3">
            <h3>
              <a href="xd2">adsssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss.</a>
            </h3>
          </div>
        </CardTop>
        <CardTop>
          <div className="Bg" />
          <div className="headerH3">
            <h3>
              <a href="xd">adssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss</a>
            </h3>
          </div>
        </CardTop>
      </NewsWrapper>
    </Container>
```

**css:**

```
export const Container = styled.div`
  background: none;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 80rem !important;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
`;

export const NewsWrapper = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  grid-row-gap: 15px;
  margin-top: 100px;
`;

export const CardTop = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  & .Bg {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    background: red;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    height: 200px;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    :hover {
      box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px 100px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }
  }
  & .headerH3 {
    padding: 0 10px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  & > div > h3 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 1rem !important;
    font-family: Roboto Slab, serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 10px 0px 10px 0 !important;
  }
  & > div > h3 > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #1976d5;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    :hover,
    :active {
      filter: brightness(115%);
    }
  }
`;
```

edit print problem:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is `grid-template-columns` as defined in your your styles doesn't allow for wrapping. Having it set as `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr` will force the browser to attempt to divide the space evenly, giving each element a quarter of the overall space.

You could instead use something akin to `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px,1fr));`, which will instead try to fit the columns dynamically (restricting their size to a minimum of 250px if the screen size does not permit larger sizing). You will need to handle the overflow within your containers themselves, but it will at least force it to wrap.

Comment: this grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px,1fr)); solve, thanks brother.